# After I did update-package in the package manager my submit button has lost is functionality and does nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a registration form and there is two inputs for password and password confirmation. When I enter distinct values I wanted it to show the error message as 'Passwords should match' or something. So I googled it and found out that update-package should fix this problem. Then I applied this solution in order to fix my problem, now, neither my error message shows up nor my submit button works.

My Registration View:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "col-12" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-horizontal p-3 m-3 w-100 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group w-100">
                <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">Kullanıcı adı</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.kullaniciAdi, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.kullaniciAdi, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group w-100">
                <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">Firma adı</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.firmaAdi, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.firmaAdi, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group w-100">
                <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">Şifre</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.sifre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required", @type = "password" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.sifre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group w-100">
                       <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">Şifre tekrar</label>
                       <div class="col-md-12">
                           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.sifreTekrar, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required", @type = "password" } })
                           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.sifre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                       </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group w-100">
                <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">E-mail</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.mail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required", @type = "text" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.mail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group w-100">
                <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">Telefon</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.telefon, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @required = "required" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.telefon, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group w-100">
                <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">Ülkeniz</label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.ulkeID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @readonly="readonly", @Value="Türkiye" } })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group w-100">
                <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">Bulunduğunuz il</label>
                <select class="form-control col-md-12" name="Address.sehirID" id="il" required></select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group w-100">
                <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">Bulunduğunuz ilçe</label>
                <select class="form-control col-md-12" name="Address.ilceID" id="ilce" disabled required>
                    <option>Bir İl Seçiniz</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group w-100">
                <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">Açık adresiniz</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.acikAdres, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @required = "required" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address.acikAdres, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group w-100">
                <label class="form-control-label col-md-12">Oluşturulma Tarihi</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.olusturulmaTarihi, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @readonly="readonly", @Value=sqlFormat } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address.acikAdres, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group w-100">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-12">
                    <input type="submit" value="Kaydol" class="btn btn-success" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     }
</div>
```

Register Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterVM model)
{
    tblKullanici user = null;
    tblAdres address = null;

    if(model != null)
    {
        db = new DatabaseContext();
        user = model.User;
        address = model.Address;
        db.tblKullanici.Add(user);
        db.tblAdres.Add(address);

        db.SaveChanges();

        if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)
        {
            Session["login"] = model.User;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "App");
        }       
    }
    ViewBag.Message = "Kayıt işlemi sırasında hata oluştu!";
    return View(model);    
}
```

jQuery

```
<script>
    // ajax call to bring district and city info dynamically according to the city value
    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            type: "post",
            url: "/User/IlIlce",// target
            dataType: "json"
        });
        $.extend({
            ilGetir: function () {
                $.ajax({
                    //sending data
                    data: { "tip": "ilGetir" },
                    success: function (sonuc) {
                        //check result if ok then append it to selectlist
                        if (sonuc.ok) {
                            $.each(sonuc.text, function (index, item) {
                                var optionhtml = '<option value="' + item.Value + '">' + item.Text + '</option>';
                                $("#il").append(optionhtml);
                            });

                        } else {
                            $.each(sonuc.text, function (index, item) {
                                var optionhtml = '<option value="' + item.Value + '">' + item.Text + '</option>';
                                $("#il").append(optionhtml);
                                $("body").append(optionhtml);
                            });

                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            ilceGetir: function (cityID) {

                $.ajax({
                    // then we get the districts with cityID
                    data: { "ilID": cityID, "tip": "ilceGetir" },
                    success: function (sonuc) {
                        // deleting records
                        $("#ilce option").remove();
                        if (sonuc.ok) {
                            // disabled to false
                            $("#ilce").prop("disabled", false);
                            $.each(sonuc.text, function (index, item) {
                                var optionhtml = '<option value="' + item.Value + '">' + item.Text + '</option>';
                                $("#ilce").append(optionhtml);
                            });

                        } else {
                            $.each(sonuc.text, function (index, item) {
                                var optionhtml = '<option value="' + item.Value + '">' + item.Text + '</option>';
                                $("#ilce").append(optionhtml);

                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        // invoke ilGetir to get city values
        $.ilGetir();
        // on change in city value
        $("#il").on("change", function () {
            // we get the id of selected value
            var cityID = $(this).val();
            // and pass it to the ilceGetir function to get the districts
            $.ilceGetir(cityID);
        });
    });
</script>
```

and the method that ajax call goes:

```cs
public JsonResult IlIlce(int? ilID, string tip)
        {
            db = new DatabaseContext();
            List<SelectListItem> sonuc = new List<SelectListItem>();
            bool isSuccessful = true;

            try
            {
                switch (tip)
                {
                    case "ilGetir":
                        // we assign the city values in db to sonuc(result) variable
                        foreach (var sehir in db.tblSehir.ToList())
                        {
                            sonuc.Add(new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = sehir.sehirAdi,
                                Value = sehir.sehirID.ToString()
                            });
                        }
                        break;

                    case "ilceGetir":
                        // we will fetch districts with sehirID(cityID)
                        foreach (var ilce in db.tblİlce.Where(il => il.bagliOlduguSehirID == ilID).ToList())
                        {
                            sonuc.Add(new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = ilce.ilceAdi,
                                Value = ilce.ilceID.ToString()
                            });
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // if we encounter an error
                isSuccessful = false;
                sonuc = new List<SelectListItem>();
                sonuc.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = e.Message,
                    Value = "Default"
                });

            }
            // i return the results as json
            return Json(new { ok = isSuccessful, text = sonuc });
        
    }
```

ilce means: district
sehir/il both means: city
sifre: password
kullaniciAdi: username
telefon: phone number
ulke: country
ilGetir : fetch city
ilceGetir: fetch district
kullanici: user
adres: address
sonuc: result
tip: type

Comment: Your code looks correct, check your JavaScript code for any piece of code that could be blocking the call to the controller.

Comment: Which package and how does it "not work"? Also, please slim it down to the relevant code only. Maybe you should also translate some words in the code.

Comment: @iamdlm I added my jQuery code to my question it seems to me right but idk if it can be an issue..

Comment: @GertArnold all I did was to type "update-package" in terminal, and when i did this, my submit button in my register view lost is functionality. When I click it nothing happens at all. Yeah sure, I ve added translation of some words at the bottom, I can translate any other part too that you need?